# How to return data by Django in Morris correctly

Tags: django, morris.js

I use the morris code for return data by Django.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Morris.Line({
        element: 'linechart',
        data: [
            {% for item in itens %}
                { uf: '{{ item.uf }}', quant:  {{ item.quant }} },
            {% endfor %}
        ],
        xkey: 'uf',
        ykeys: ['quant'],
        labels: ['quant'],
        hideHover: 'auto',
        resize: true,
    });
</script>
```

but return dots

[image]

The data is return by Django queryset

The output is

AM  10

SP  5

RJ  15

RN  20

TO  10

Comment: Can you post an example of what the `data` array contains?

Comment: I edit question again.

Comment: Your x coordinates must be numeric, not strings

Comment: OK, One more thing: I can not separate it into a .js file? gives error

Comment: That is because separate JS files do not get rendered by the Django template engine thus you cannot use such things as `{% for item in itens %}`. What I would advise you is to make this data available through a JSON view, which you would call from a static JS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then i used barchart.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        Morris.Bar({
            element: 'barchart',
            data: [
                {% for item in itens %}
                    { uf: '{{ item.uf }}', quant:  {{ item.quant }} },
                {% endfor %}
            ],
            xkey: 'uf',
            ykeys: ['quant'],
            labels: ['quant'],
            hideHover: 'auto',
            resize: true,
        });
    </script>
```